# What VST should I use to make my microphone sound like a PA system?

Tags: vst

I was wondering what VST effect I should use in order to make my microphone sound like a PA system.  I was listening to different ones and it seemed like the reverb is good to make it sound echoy, but not sure how to make it "lower quality" sounding.

Here is a video showcasing similar to what I want:

Answer (score 4):

A similar effect can be produced using an EQ alone. Boost the mids to the point that they are almost clipping and reduce the highs and lows. Many EQs come with a preset for this.

If you put a small amount of distortion before and after the EQ it will improve the effect.

[image: A quick proof of concept in Logic Pro's pedal board. Signal flows from left to right.]

Answer (score 0):

[Audioease Speakerphone](https://www.audioease.com/Pages/Speakerphone/speakerphone.html) is commonly used to easily achieve this type of effects.

Comment: Is there a free alternative?